# How to delete files of a directory in a web server periodically?

Tags: cron

I want to display a file upload demo in my website.
So I need to delete all the files in the *uploads* directory every one hour.
I am using a remotely hosted platform( linux).
I want to know how to implement this.

How to delete files of a directory in a web server periodically?

I think it can be implemented using cron job but I don't have much knowledge about cron jobs
So please answer in detail.

I tried browsing all the answers in stackoverflow website I didn't find any questions answering my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `crontab -e` to edit your crontab. I am assuming you have shell access to your server of course.

Then add the following line:
`0 * * * * rm -f /path/to/dir/*`

I believe `crontab` defaults to `vim` as an editor, so if you are not familiar, just remember: press `i` to begin editing, then `Esc` to return to command mode, followed by `:wq` to write to file and quit.

If you don't have shell access to your server...then best I can think of is having PHP/whatever backend you are using check the time on every request.

Comment: I am using cpanel, can you please advise me how to implement this in cpanel

Comment: @Praveen - please let me know if this link helps you, it describes how to set up cron in cpanel: http://www.upstartblogger.com/how-to-create-a-cron-job-in-cpanel

Answer (score 0):

every 15 min and every hour and day and moth delete files *.php

```
 15 * * * * find /domaine_path/ -mtime +7 -type f -name "*.php" -exec rm -f {} \;
```